# Leveraging graphviz to create a network weathermap configuration

Tags: graphviz

Given a generated list of nodes and links, is there a way I can use dot or some other tool from the graphviz package to create coordinates for those nodes such that I in turn can use that information to generate a configuration file for network weathermap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, calling dot or the other tools without an output argument printed the information I wanted to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this shell script to make a graph from an mrtg config file, but decided to not pursue the weathermap part, due to the results being too cluttered;

```
grep -P '^SetEnv.*MRTG_INT_IP="..*" MRTG_INT_DESCR=".*"' $1 | grep -v 'MRTG_INT_IP="127.' | grep -v 'MRTG_INT_IP="10.255.' |\
sed \
    -e 's/SetEnv\[\(.*\.switch\.hapro\.no_.*\)]: MRTG_INT_IP="\(.*\)" MRTG_INT_DESCR="\(.*\)"/\1 \2 \3/' \
    -e 's/\//_/g' |\
sort -t/ -k 1 -n -k 2 -n -k 3 -n -k 4 |\
gawk '
BEGIN { print "graph '$2' {"; }
{
        graph[overlap=false];
        v = "'$2'"
        print v " -- " $3
}
END { print "}" }'
```

Thought I would share this in case someone else found it useful in the future.

I used the script like `./mkconf ../switch/mrtg.1c.conf 1c | dot -Tpng > test.png`